# how to send data from notification to application

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I use this tutorial for notifications in my app http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/

Each notification has action - Edit.  I add Observer for it, in viewDidLoad() method:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleModifyListNotification", name: "modifyListNotification", object: nil)
```

When press button Edit in notification, app call this method:

```
func handleModifyListNotification() {

    }
```

for assign notification I use:

```
func scheduleLocalNotification() {
        var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComp.year = 2015;
        dateComp.month = 02;
        dateComp.day = 24;
        dateComp.hour = 14;
        dateComp.minute = 34;
        dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
        var calender:NSCalendar? = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
        var date:NSDate = calender!.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!
        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = fixNotificationDate(date)
        localNotification.alertBody = "Hey, you must go shopping, remember?"
        localNotification.alertAction = "View List"
        localNotification.category = "shoppingListReminderCategory"
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
```

But how can I send data to this method to know which notification call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `notification` like following,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleModifyListNotification:", name: "modifyListNotification", object: nil)
```

with `colon` in `Selector`.

and `Post your notification` like,

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("modifyListNotification", object: "Your Object Value")
```

and your function should be,

```
func handleModifyListNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    NSLog("Object is %@", notification.valueForKey("object") as String!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I post notification by time (see edited post). What to do in my example?

Comment: you're scheduling local notification to the function itself.? what you want to pass and where you want to pass, can you put some comments in your code.

Comment: I want to add: Use  localNotification.userInfo field to send data from active notification to app